# How can I get 1080p to work on my TV with HDMI using xrandr?

Tags: arch-linux, x11, nvidia, xrandr, hdmi

I'm using Arch Linux on a small HTPC called an [Xtreamer](http://dev.xtreamer.net/xtreamer/overview.aspx), which has an Nvidia GT218/ION graphics card and HDMI out. My television is an [Orion DL40-71BK](http://www.orion-electric.co.jp/jp/discon/dl40-71bk/) ([manual](http://www.orion-electric.co.jp/jp/wp-content/themes/toolbox/manual/dl40-71bk.pdf), note everything's in Japanese).

HDMI video output works fine on some settings, for example 1440x900 and 1280x720, and xrandr shows many modes without any X11 configuration, including 1920x1080@60Hz (which it lists as the preferred mode). Full xrandr output follows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192                     
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)              
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                      
HDMI-0 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.05 +  60.00    59.94    60.00                                    
   1440x900      59.89*                                                              
   1360x768      60.02                                                               
   1280x1024     60.02                                                               
   1280x768      59.87                                                               
   1280x720      60.00    59.94                                                      
   1024x768      60.00                                                               
   800x600       60.32                                                               
   720x480       59.94    60.05                                                      
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

One thing I do not understand here: What are the columns to the right of 60.00 in the 1920x1080 line?

Anyway, the problem is if I use xrandr to switch to the 1920x1080 mode (or let X11 do so by default on startup) my television shows a black screen and an error (非対応の入力信号, "unsupported input signal"). This also happens if I use the `nvidia-settings` tool to set the resolution (it also lists 1920x1080 as supported, but has the same error).

I can find this error a few places online, but nothing to with Linux, just people having problems with game consoles and older versions of the TV.

I know the TV works with 1920x1080; the manufacturer lists it and my PS3 uses 1080p just fine.

**What can I do to use 1920x1080 on my TV?**　Is there some configuration I've overlooked?

Comment: The other numbers on the 1920x1080 line are refresh rates (can be set in xrandr using the `-r` flag). No idea why 60.00 is shown twice in that line though. Have you tried specifying both the mode and one of those refresh rates at the same time?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I guess the default refresh rate wasn't working with my TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to brm's comment and reading the `xrandr` man page, I figured out what the issue was. There were two problems:

First, I'd always used xrandr's `-s` option, which specifies size, rather than the newer `--mode` option. This almost always works anyway, and in this case switching to `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080` didn't fix things. However, it was needed to deal with the second problem: refresh rates.

Apparently the default refresh rate for 1920x1080 wasn't actually supported by my TV (thus the signal error), so I had to specify 60Hz. `xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 60` gave the error `Rate 60.00 Hz not available for this size`, as did using any of the other frequences listed in the xrandr output.

The final solution was to use this command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 -r 60
```

And everything works nicely. I'm still not sure *exactly* why this works, especially since the man page says `-r` (a 1.1 option) shouldn't work well with `--mode` (a 1.2 option). But I'm happy to have my pixels at least.